# Find values in multiple columns simultaneously

Tags: excel, matching

I have columns A, B, C, and D. I would like to write a formula that would return `Yes` or `No` only if the value in column A also appears in columns B, C, and D simultaneously.

[image]

Comment: Look into the [COUNTIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842)

Comment: So if **A1** contains ***happy***, you want to check if ***happy*** exists anywhere in column **B** and column **C** and column **D** ??

Comment: I want to write a formula in column E for example, that would output "Yes", if Happy is found in column B and column C, and column D. If happy is only found in column B and C, I want it to output "No".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below formula as in image in column E,

```
=IF(AND(COUNTIF(B:B,A1),COUNTIF(C:C,A1),COUNTIF(C:C,A1)),"Yes","No")
```

[image]

Comment: So yes, that is the concept that I am looking for. Now what if column B, C, and D are lists and "Happy" can at any cell number in those list. How would I modify the formula for that? Thanks.

Comment: @ygao85 If Happy is in cell F2 for example, just replace the "Happy" with $F$2.

Comment: I've Uploaded a picture of what I would like the end result to be :)

Comment: @ygao85 You want `yes` in just one cell, if `happy` is present in anywhere in column A and anywhere in column B and so on?? am i right?

Comment: Yes,  column A will have column A will have uniqueIDs, i want column E to say Yes, if the same uniqueID in column shows up anywhere in column, B, C, D, simultaneously.

Comment: @ygao85 I have updated the answer. Please check and let me know if it works

Answer (score 1):

Use the following formula in cell E2, and copy and paste to the rest of the column

```
=if(and(a2=b2,b2=c2,c2=d2),"Yes","No")
```